# Validating android preferences and showing a dialog box

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to validate preference text entered by the user and show a dialog in case of error. But the app crashes when dialog box is trying to display with error below:

02-11 16:50:04.117: E/AndroidRuntime(3769): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@4055feb0 is not valid; is your activity running?

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: how abt you share the code of your dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is old, but was an early google hit, so hopefully this helps someone. Here's something I hacked together today.

in your fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        Your_Pref = (EditTextPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("Your_Pref");

        Your_Pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                Boolean rtnval = true;
                if (Your_Test) {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle("Invalid Input");
                    builder.setMessage("Something's gone wrong...");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.show();
                    rtnval = false;
                }
                return rtnval;
            }
        });
    }
```